# AWS CLI Command modify / crop output?

Tags: amazon-web-services, output, aws-cli

I'm seeking ways to crop the output of individual fields using the AWS CLI --query flag.

For example, I can pipe to the `cut` command to cut parts of each line, but this requires a manual effort of counting the characters in the name.

```
$ aws --region us-east-1 cloudwatch describe-alarms \
     --query 'MetricAlarms[*].{AlarmName:AlarmName,MetricName:MetricName,Namespace:Namespace,Threshold:Threshold,Time:StateUpdatedTimestamp,State:StateValue}' \
     --output table | cut -c1-50,97-147,197-500
```

Anyone know of a creative way to do this, without having to already know the (variable length) field length?

1. A way to change the MetricName field as a part of the --query, so the table only displays the first 50 chars of the metric?

OR

2. A way to pipe to a command that will limit the length between the pipes in the cli table output to a max of 50 chars?

OR

3. Output from the aws command as JSON, change the fields (using jq maybe?) and then output the json to a table similar to what the `aws <command> --output table` would?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could get is a pipe-delimited output where you can specify max length of string fields using below example.. you will then need to do some more work if you need it exactly the way `--output table` gives you.. listed below is the example that produces pipe-delimited output with all string fields truncated to length 10

`aws cloudwatch describe-alarms --query 'MetricAlarms[*].{"AlarmName":"AlarmName","MetricName":"MetricName","Namespace":"Namespace","Threshold":"Threshold","Time":"StateUpdated","State":"StateValue"}' --output json | jq '.[][] |= (if type == "string" then .[0:10] else .|tostring end) | .[] | join(" | ") '`

Listed below is the output it provides

```
"TargetTrac | ConsumedWr | AWS/Dynamo | 210 | null | OK"
"TargetTrac | Provisione | AWS/Dynamo | 5 | null | OK"
"TargetTrac | Provisione | AWS/Dynamo | 5 | null | OK"
"TargetTrac | ConsumedWr | AWS/Dynamo | 210 | null | OK"
"TargetTrac | Provisione | AWS/Dynamo | 5 | null | OK"
"TargetTrac | Provisione | AWS/Dynamo | 5 | null | OK"
```